# Is library.readscheme.org permanently down? Where was it moved?

Tags: scheme

Does somebody knows what happened to `library.readscheme.org`?  Since last September (2018) the server seems to have been closed.

Is there other place where the links to the literature were moved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the Web Archive:

- https://web.archive.org/web/20180625085633/http://library.readscheme.org/

Seems the page hasn't been updated since 2012 or so, though.

Comment: The library's page from archive.org was down for about 1 week.  Now it seems it works again.  Could we rely on archive.org that they preserve the library ?

Comment: @alinsoar who knows anything at this point. except maybe downloading it all and making a hard copy.

Comment: I also discovered recently this mirror --  I hope they preserve it up: http://mirror.informatimago.com/scheme/library.readscheme.org/index.html